# SQL: Summing columns with a similar column in common

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm extremely new to SQL Sever and so I apologize if the question is worded strange. I am doing a homework assignment, and this is the question:

*"A manager wants to know the email address, number or orders, and the total amount of purchases made by each customer. Create a summary query that returns these three items for each customer that has orders."*

I have all of the data queried, the problem is when I pull data from each customer, it will show the quantity of items per order, and I need the items to be pooled together into one column. This is my query thus far (again, total noob, please excuse any poor syntax, etc.)

```
SELECT EmailAddress,
ItemPrice - DiscountAmount * Quantity AS TotalPurchaseAmount,
COUNT(*) AS OrderQty
FROM Customers
JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
JOIN OrderItems ON Orders.OrderID = OrderItems.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.CustomerID, 
OrderItems.ItemPrice, OrderItems.DiscountAmount,
OrderItems.Quantity,
Customers.EmailAddress;
```

The following is a small bit of the result set that I get:

```
Email Address               OrderTotal  OrderQty
allan.sherwood@yahoo.com    253.15      2
allan.sherwood@yahoo.com    839.30      2
allan.sherwood@yahoo.com    1208.16     2
barryz@gmail.com            303.79      4
christineb@solarone.com     479.60      2
david.goldstein@hotmail.com 299.00      2
david.goldstein@hotmail.com 489.30      1
david.goldstein@hotmail.com 479.60      1
```

So as you can see, I have several orders I need to smoosh together into one single row per e-mail, I have looked and looked for an answer but the only thing I can find is how to find duplicates and ignore them, not combine their data. Any help is extremely appreciate, thanks so much for taking the time to read this :) If my question doesn't make sense please let me know so I can clear up any bad wording I may have used!

Comment: you need to review your formula. Is discount different for each record?

Comment: Yes, it's just the total amount that was taken off, it's not a percentage or anything so it just needs subtracted off. Although now that I'm looking at it the order of operations kinda exists huh........I'll fix that, thanks!

Comment: trevor : cheers mate..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `GROUP BY CustomerID, EmailAddress`:

```
SELECT
    c.EmailAddress,
    SUM((i.ItemPrice - i.DiscountAmount) * Quantity) AS TotalPurchaseAmount,
    COUNT(*) AS OrderQty
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o
    ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrderItems i
    ON o.OrderID = i.OrderID
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerID, c.EmailAddress
```

*Additional note: Use aliases for your tables*

Comment: I really hate how easy the solution always is when it comes to this stuff.....hahaha, in my defense we had no teacher this week and our book is total garbage so I'm sorta struggling through this section, Thank you so much, that fixed it :)

Comment: As an aside, our teacher takes off points if we do tables aliases, he thinks it makes queries sloppy.

Comment: No it does not. Not aliasing your tables makes your query hard to read. However, when aliasing your tables, be sure that the aliases used are meaningful. You can't just alias `Order` table with `a`.

Comment: Oh no, I agree, I would love to use them, I was just letting you know why I didn't use them (I'd lose points)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your formula and remove columns that you dont want to group by from select query..
for example your query should be something like this

```
SELECT EmailAddress,
--do your aggregation here
blah AS TotalPurchaseAmount,
COUNT(*) AS OrderQty
FROM Customers
JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
JOIN OrderItems ON Orders.OrderID = OrderItems.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.CustomerID, 
Customers.EmailAddress;
```